# eBook-speaker in the Siftware is Broken

Tags: 14.04

Please help the blind and visually impaired in your country and translate daisy-player
eBook-speaker Version 5.0.1 (source code) ( PGP signature )
Available as a Ubuntu package since 12.04 (Precise Pangolin).

```
Daisy-player Version 11.3.2 (source code) ( PGP signature )
Available as a Ubuntu package since 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot).
A RPM source kit for Fedora made by Johan Vromans .

- A full featured DAISY cd player for Linux
```

Comment: This thing cahneged my informatuim. I want to install http://jlemmens.nl/ reader for blind people, daisy but the obselite verson won't noe werk

Comment: What is wrong with `sudo apt-get install daisy-player`? It [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=daisy-player).